# Why tkinter frame is not the same size as the Tk window with grid method?

Tags: tkinter

I am probably being dim here but I can't figure out why the `ttk.Frame` widget in this simple script isn't growing with the `Tk` window when the window is resizing and when the Grid method is used? I don't expect the `ttk.Label` with the image to resize with the window by default. However, I was expecting to see pink color (background color of the frame) surrounding the label when the window is larger than the label given that methods `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` were used. Where is my mistake?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk 

IMAGE = './images/test.jpg'


class App( ttk.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, master, **kwargs ):
        self.master = master

        super().__init__( master, style='app.TFrame', **kwargs  )

        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage( Image.open( IMAGE ) )
        self.screen = ttk.Label( self, image=photo, style='app.TLabel' )
        self.screen.image = photo
        self.screen.grid( row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew' )


def init_ttkStyle():
    '''Initialize ttk widget styles.'''
    s = ttk.Style()            
    s.configure( 'app.TFrame', background='pink' )
    s.configure( 'app.TLabel', background='cyan', borderwidth=10, relief='ridge' )
    return s


def main():
    ROOT = tk.Tk()
    appStyle = init_ttkStyle()
    app = App( ROOT )
    app.grid( row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew' )  # ?
    app.columnconfigure( 0, weight=1 )          # ?
    app.rowconfigure( 0, weight=1 )             # ?
    #app.pack( expand=1, fill='both' )            #this works
    ROOT.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app` is a `Frame` widget. When you use `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` on a `Frame` widget, it will grid as per your specification, **but** the `root` window will not. It works in the case of `.pack`, as it has been explicitly told to `expand` and `fill` the complete `root` window.

To make it work in a similar fashion, perform the `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` on `root`.

Comment: Spot on. I should have `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` `ROOT` instead of `app`. My bad.... ;)